# Adding columns in Spark dataframe based on rules

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe df, which contains below data:

```
**customers**   **product**   **Val_id**
     1               A            1
     2               B            X
     3               C               
     4               D            Z
```

i have been provided 2 rules, which are as below:

```
**rule_id**   **rule_name**  **product value**  **priority**
   123              ABC             A,B               1
   456              DEF             A,B,D             2
```

Requirement is to apply these rules on dataframe df in priority order, customers who have passed rule 1, should not be considered for rule 2 and in final dataframe add two more columns rule_id and rule_name, i have written below code to achieve it:

```
val rule_name = when(col("product").isin("A","B"), "ABC").otherwise(when(col("product").isin("A","B","D"), "DEF").otherwise(""))
val rule_id = when(col("product").isin("A","B"), "123").otherwise(when(col("product").isin("A","B","D"), "456").otherwise(""))
val df1 = df_customers.withColumn("rule_name" , rule_name).withColumn("rule_id" , rule_id)
df1.show()
```

Final output looks like below:

```
**customers**   **product**   **Val_id**  **rule_name**  **rule_id**
     1               A            1           ABC            123
     2               B            X           ABC            123
     3               C               
     4               D            Z           DEF            456
```

Is there any better way to achieve it, adding both columns by just going though entire dataset once instead of going through entire dataset twice?